# grab_set issue with tkinter toplevel window

Tags: python-3, gui, tkinter

I'm having an issue with the grab_set command when opening a toplevel window on my Pi. I'm using a grab_set to disable the screen below the toplevel and releasing it on close of the window.

I doesn't happen every time but on occasion I will get this error:
_tkinter.TclError: grab failed: window not viewable

The window will appear but the grab didn't work.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `wait_visibility()` before `grab_set()`.